# JavaScript and SVG: how do you increase the clickable area for an onClick event?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, svg

My script draws lines on the screen at a stroke-width of 3. The size of lines are ideal (visually) but they aren't very easy to click.

As a rough example:

```js
    function selectStrand(evt) {
        current_id = evt.target.getAttributeNS(null, "id");

        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = current_id;
    }
```

```html
    Selected line: <span id="main"></span>
                      
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
        <g id="buffer" transform="translate(10,0)">
          <line id="blue-blue" x1="50" y1="50" x2="500" y2="50" style="stroke:blue; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-orange" x1="50" y1="70" x2="500" y2="70" style="stroke:orange; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-green" x1="50" y1="90" x2="500" y2="90" style="stroke:green; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-brown" x1="50" y1="110" x2="500" y2="110" style="stroke:brown; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-grey" x1="50" y1="130" x2="500" y2="130" style="stroke:grey; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-khaki" x1="50" y1="150" x2="500" y2="150" style="stroke:khaki; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-red" x1="50" y1="170" x2="500" y2="170" style="stroke:red; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-black" x1="50" y1="190" x2="500" y2="190" style="stroke:black; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-yellow" x1="50" y1="210" x2="500" y2="210" style="stroke:yellow; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-purple" x1="50" y1="230" x2="500" y2="230" style="stroke:purple; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-pink" x1="50" y1="250" x2="500" y2="250" style="stroke:pink; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
          <line id="blue-cyan" x1="50" y1="270" x2="500" y2="270" style="stroke:cyan; stroke-width: 4;" stroke-linecap="round" onclick="selectStrand(evt)"/>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

Is there a simple way to increase the area around each of the lines to make them easier to click?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For each line, try drawing a transparent line on top of it with a larger stroke width, and set the onclick on that.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks. That works and seems like it is the best way.

Comment: You might want to add the click event listener to the root or the group with id=buffer in your example, and look at the target of the event you get to figure out which line was clicked. That way you only need one event listener, instead of one on each element.

Oh, and the `<?xml ... ?>` part is not necessary when including the svg inline in html, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on the above answer. For a cool selection effect group each thin line and transparent line combo in a group with the thin line on top. Set the onclick to the group and then animate the transparency of the thick line in your onclick.

Comment: Ya,  I was considering doing something flashy with onClick once I figured out the overall mechanics... sounds like a good idea. Thanks for the tip!